# Как склонять "Исследовательский центр - филиал медицинского центра"

Tags: склонение, названия

Как склонять название места работы **Исследовательский центр - филиал медицинского центра** (кавычек нет)? Авторы названия настаивают на таком склонении: *в  Исследовательском центре - филиал...*

Comment: Полностью название напишите. Филиал какого центра? У него есть название?

Comment: "Авторы названия настаивают на таком склонении: в Исследовательском центре - филиал..." - а чем мотивируют?!

Answer (score 1):

"в Исследовательском центре - филиал..." - в смысле, что вторая часть названия не склоняется вовсе? Нет, такое не пойдет.

Поскольку название цельное, то как несогласованное приложение это не проходит. Если "авторы" хотят таким образом подчеркнуть второстепенность, подчиненность второй части, то это желается или скобками (тогда можно и не слонять), или, как вы упомянули, кавычками, подводя базу под понимание второй части как имени собственного. В обоих случаях тире не нужно.

Подобные же образования придется склонять полностью, даже принимая к сведению, что главное слово тут "институт", а филиал - приложение.

Не знаю, может тут и грамматика другая, но я вижу так.

Comment: "Поскольку название цельное" - это, конечно, аргументация выше всякой критики. А не обратить ли  внимание на то, что  в "цельных названиях" первое слово может не склоняться, а вот второе (при склоняемом первом) не склоняться не может. И верно это  в любом случае, что бы Вы там ни поставили: дефис, короткое тире или длинное/классическое. (Это всего лишь такое наблюдение, отнюдь не аргументация). Кстати, будьте любезны, обоснуйте постановку тире в подобных названиях ссылкой из правил. А я пока исправлю ответ, внесу тире как возможный вариант.

Comment: *Подобные же образования придется склонять полностью...* Хоть я и плохо понимаю суть названий, мне тоже кажется единственно возможным вариантом склонять всё.

Comment: *Хоть я и плохо понимаю суть названий* - во-первых, что тут непонятного, какая-такая суть? А во-вторых, грамматика - она как обертка, ей *внеграмматическая* суть не важна. Семантика - это другой вопрос.

Comment: *"Поскольку название цельное" - это, конечно, аргументация выше всякой критики* - нет, это агрументация у меня не это. Вы опять пеоказали, что Вам интереснее просто возразить не понимая смысла.  Аргументация то, что вторая часть - приложение, а оно не может быть несогласованным, в данном по крайней мере случае. Вот поэтому   я и предлагал Вам прежде чем критиковать, формулировать мысль, которую собрались оспаривать.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще говоря, в русском языке при дефисном написании (или, возможно,  написании через тире) двух склоняемых существительных **может не склоняться**  только первая часть: адрес-календарь, интернет-проект, караван-сарай, марш-бросок, онлайн-опрос, пиар-акция, плащ-палатка и т. д.  (Иногда первая часть представляет собой несклоняемое существительное, например, кафе-автомат. Здесь **мы просто наблюдаем** за подобными написаниями, пока не затрагивая тему вопроса.)

**Поэтому и выбор может делаться для первой части, несклоняемая вторая часть при склоняемой первой выглядит по меньшей мере странно.** (А это уже **вывод,** который можно распространить на все назывные написания, в том числе из заданного вопроса.)

Comment: Да Вы что? Разве этот случай относится к упомянутому Вами примеру? Разве это дефис, а не тире? Тут два слова в первой части, а у Вас везде одно. А дефисом разделяются, как я всегда считал, одиночные слова, а не словосочетания. Разве нет?

Comment: Может быть, и тире. Вообще-то здесь терминология достаточно сложная, например, платье-костюм, ковер-самолет, сад-ясли - это сложные наименования, потому что первый элемент склоняется, а премьер-министр, жар-птица, царь-колокол,  шеф-повар - сложные слова, потому что первый элемент не склоняется. Поэт-новатор и горе-охотник - это словосочетания приложения/определения и существительного. При этом все эти варианты имеют одно и то же дефисное написание.  Я как раз тоже думаю: а названия/наименования организаций могут писаться через тире?

Comment: Артём Луговой, здесь тире, но оно заменяет собой дефис между составляющими из более чем одного слова, на принципах склонения это не сказывается.  Это-то как раз верно. Вот остальное - это да...  Аргументация ниже всякой критики.

Comment: Эти составляющие из более чем одного слова  - это, скорее, устойчивые сочетания, но не официальные названия организаций.

Comment: "...на принципах склонения это не сказывается". Конечно, сам выбор между тире и дефисом на склонении не сказывается, но вот количество слов, мне казалось, влияет на него. Я только не могу себе представить, в каком контексте надо говорить полностью это сочетание, и вообще мне нужно получше понять, как связаны между собой медицинский и исследовательский центр, чтобы судить. А, не понимая, как всё увязано, мне это кажется бессмысленным набором слов. :(

Comment: *вот количество слов, мне казалось, влияет на него* - нет. Влияет только выбор модели грамматики. А грамматика (в имеющихся системах, то что предлагает Sergey - это его личная модель, обсуждать не хочется) допускает только два варианта. Или две части представляю собой сочетания равноценных элементов "кресло-кровать", "фабрика -- молочная кухня", "домашнее задание -- контрольная работа" или одно является приложением к другому.  В первом случае приходится склонять обе части, во втором надо смотреть что чему является приложением, а что главным элементом. Вот вкратце.

Comment: *ти составляющие из более чем одного слова - это, скорее, устойчивые сочетания, но не официальные названия организаций* - это именно официальное название. Иначе и вопроса бы не было. Да и кому пришло бы в голову такое употребить в качестве устойчивого сочетания - а потом биться за него во имя несклонения?

Comment: 1) Кресло-кровать, фабрика -- молочная кухня: в этих сочетаниях нет безусловной сочинительной  связи, так как  второй элемент ЧАСТИЧНО подчинен другому по смыслу и стоит на втором месте, как и положено классическому приложению.  Примеры с чисто сочинительной связью: хлеб-соль, вопросы-ответы. 2) Приложение определяется как определение, выраженное существительным и СОГЛАСОВАННОЕ в падеже с определяемым словом.  Если склонения/согласования нет, то это составное наименование (из Грамматики-80).

Comment: В этом случае несклоняемое приложение стоит на первом месте, на второе место его никто не ставит. Поэтому делаем вывод, что несклоняемый элемент может находиться только на пером месте, но не на втором (написание через дефис или тире). Это не так? Тогда приведите, пожалуйста, пример хотя бы какого-нибудь  сочетания (через дефис или тире), где первый элемент склоняется, а второй нет.

Comment: И еще одно замечание (для Артема). Если текст кажется вам набором бессмысленных фраз, это не значит,  что он действительно не имеет никакого смысла. (Возможно, что вы просто незнакомы с этой темой). Можете поставить минус (и это будет, безусловно, одобрено), можете зачеркнуть и забыть, но вам это не прибавит знаний.